# Android: Could not find class 'com.google.android.gms.location.internal.ParcelableGeofence referenced from method glt.a

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services

Google Maps API was working fine until recently. I assume the issue stems from a google play services update. Looked through similar questions on stackoverflow, but there does not seem to be a working solution yet.

Here is the logcat with the error I get from Google Maps API:

```
08-19 16:28:37.746: E/dalvikvm(4868): Could not find class 'gpq', referenced from method gpr.a
08-19 16:28:37.746: E/dalvikvm(4868): Could not find class 'gpq', referenced from method gpr.a
08-19 16:28:37.746: E/dalvikvm(4868): Could not find class 'gpq', referenced from method gpr.a
08-19 16:28:38.016: E/dalvikvm(4868): Could not find class 'com.google.android.gms.location.internal.ParcelableGeofence', referenced from method gls.a
```

In my layout, I am referencing Google Maps as follows:

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

In my activity, I get the map with this code:

```
mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

The markers and lines I am drawing on the map are showing up, but the map itself does not seem to be loading. As a result, I end up with markers, lines, and a Google maps grid with no map.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think this error is related to the map not showing up.  I have the same error reported in LogCat and my map is displayed as expected. I have not verified this, but I suspect the issue is also related to missing Geofence classes.  I also get the error using sdk API 19:

```
Could not find class 'com.google.android.gms.location.internal.ParcelableGeofence' referenced from method gls.a
```